# Twitter Bootstrap date picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I use the Twitter Bootstrap date picker? I used the code below but its not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>DatePicker Demo</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <link href="css/datepicker.less" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form >
        <div class="input">
            <input class="small" type="text" value="01/05/2011" data-datepicker="datepicker">
        </div>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're confusing different datepickers. You're asking about bootstrap-datepicker, and that's what you seem to be including in your `<script>` tag, but your `<input>` includes the attribute `data-datepicker="datepicker"`, which isn't a bootstrap-datepicker thing at all. I don't even know what datepicker library uses that attribute - it's not jQuery UI Datepicker either. Anyway, I've posted [a quickstart guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20984433/1709587) to using the actual bootstrap-datepicker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is incompatible with jQuery UI styles at the moment.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/156

This might help you https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin ( http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/drafts/new )

Comment: The question is about bootstrap-datepicker, not jQuery UI Datepicker. jQuery UI isn't relevant.

Answer (score 68):

The most popular bootstrap date picker is currently: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker 
(thanks to [@dentarg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525616/dentarg) for digging it up)

A simple instantiation only requires:

HTML

```
<input class="datepicker">
```

Javascript

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

See a simple example here https://jsfiddle.net/k6qsm5no/1/ or the full docs here http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: In the fiddle, nothing happens when I click on the textbox, isn't it supposed to pop up the picker?

Answer (score 30):

Much confusion stems from the existence of at least three major libraries named bootstrap-datepicker:

1. **A popular fork of eyecon's datepicker by Andrew 'eternicode' Rowls *(use this one!)*:**

   - [Online demo, plus download link for the latest release version](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)
   - [Comprehensive documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
   - [GitHub repo](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)
2. The original version by Stefan 'eyecon' Petre, still available at http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/
3. A totally unrelated datepicker widget that 'storborg' [sought to have merged into bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/614). It wasn't merged and no proper release version of the widget was ever created.

If you're starting a new project - or heck, even if you're taking over an old project using the eyecon version - I recommend that you ***use eternicode's version, not eyecon's***. The original eyecon version is outright inferior in terms of both functionality and documentation, and this is unlikely to change - it has not been updated since March 2013.

You can see most of the capabilities of the eternicode datepicker on [the demo page](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) which lets you play with the datepicker's configuration and observe the results. For more detail, see the [succinct but comprehensive documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which you can probably consume in its entirety in under an hour.

In case you're impatient, though, here's a very short step-by-step guide to the simplest and most common use case for the datepicker.

### Quick start guide

1. Include the following libraries (minimum versions noted [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#requirements)) on your page:

   - [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
   - [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) - both the JS and CSS
   - [The latest release version of bootstrap-datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) - both the JS and CSS
2. Put an `input` element on your page somewhere, e.g.

   ```
   <input id="my-date-input">
   ```
3. With jQuery, select your input and call the `.datepicker()` method:

   ```
   jQuery('#my-date-input').datepicker();
   ```
4. Load your page and click on or tab into your `input` element. A datepicker will appear:

   [image: Picture of a datepicker]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem but when I created a test project, to my surprise, datepicker worked perfectly using Bootstrap v2.0.2 and Jquery UI 1.8.11. Here are the scripts i'm including:

```
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jquery Bootstrap:

http://jslegers.github.com/jquery-bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

add

```
z-index:1151;
```

to the style sheet in

```
.datepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom theme with themeroller, then on the download page, choose 'Advanced Theme Settings'. **Set the CSS scope to 'body'**. Since the CSS rules you download will be prefixed with the body tag selector, they'll have higher specificity and will **override bootstrap rules**.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem for twitter-bootstrap.

As [eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) is incompatible with jQuery UI.

But twitter-bootstrap is working fine for [vitalets/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/vitalets/bootstrap-datepicker) even with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Some people posted the [link](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) to this bootstrap-datepicker.js implementation. I used that one in the following way, it works with Bootstrap 3.

This is the markup I used:

```
<div class="input-group date col-md-3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="01-01-2014">                        
    <input id="txtHomeLoanStartDate" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="" value="01-01-2014" size="14" />
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$('.date').datepicker();
```

I also included the javascript file downloaded from the link above, along with it's css file, and of course, you should remove any bootstrap grid classes like the `col-md-3` to suit your needs.

Comment: Note that the eyecon datepicker is no longer maintained, but was forked by eternicode. You should use eternicode's (currently maintained, more fully-featured and properly documented) version instead: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You used `data-datepicker="datepicker"` It must be `date-provide="datepicker"`

Also, you included 2 bootstrap stylesheets `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`

I also prefer to use `bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css` than `datepicker.less`

**Full Html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>DatePicker Demo</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="input">
                <input data-provide="datepicker" class="small" type="text" value="01/05/2011">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```