# How to use bootstrap and jquery dropdown on same page

Tags: jquery, date, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to use bootstrap date and time picker ,I already using the file "jquery.dropdown.js" to do some other dropdown in my page..But date and time picker does not work on including the jquery and bootstrap dropdown files on the same page.(i.e including "jquery.dropdown.js" and "bootstrap-dropdown.js" )

Suggest me any possible way of handling events from bootstrap and jquery dropdown in same page...

Comment: Why don't you just include jquery.dropdown.js where necessary? Or replace it with the bootstrap one, where you use it?

Comment: For the menu kind of items it is good to use bootstap ..but when including many links to dropdown in same page bootstrap increases the code content that is every time there is a need to create the dropdown options.. but using jquery dropdown allows to create menu once and that can be called from the whole document.. so only i trying to use both files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267858/twitter-bootstrap-date-picker may help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use both bootstrap and jquery dropdown on same page.....better change it to use anyone.