# Laravel 6: how i can calculate age using datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

i have been wondering how i can calculate age using bootstrap datepicker

This is my datepicker

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            yearRange: '-100y:c+nn',
            maxDate: '1d'
        });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi Putri - I'm struggling to find an actual question here. At which particular point are you stuck?

Comment: hi @Lewis can you give me example how to calculate age using datepicker with date format yy-mm-dd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267858/twitter-bootstrap-date-picker)